# Composer: Why isn't my namespaced model autoloading in Laravel4?

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php, autoload

I feel like I've tried a million different things according to tons of questions/answers already on SO about this ... but I'm still missing something. (This is a Laravel 4 project.)

I added a business logic directory to my models path to be like `app/models/businesslogic`.
In that directory is `CcGateway.php` which is namespaced as `namespace BusinessLogic;`.

In my `composer.json`, I started out by trying

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/models/businesslogic"
    ],
```

After a `composer dump-autoload`, it still throws:

> Class 'BusinessLogic\CcGateway' not found

So I tried both

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\models\\": "app/models"
        },
```

and

```
        "App\\models\\businesslogic\\": "app/models/businesslogic"
```

to no avail.

Lastly, I tried changing the name space (in both the class script and the `use` statement, but no changes to `composer.json`) to `Models\BusinessLogic`, but still, no luck.

I know this is *supposed* to be easy, so I must be overlooking or misunderstanding something simple. What is it?

Answer (score 0):

You model directory is named in lowercase (app/models/businesslogic) but your namespace is in Capital (BusinessLogic). Try renaming your directory to match "BusinessLogic".

Also, you really don't need to add anything to your classmap or PSR-4, as the models directory is already included in the standard classmap config, and will automatically pickup any subdirectories.